# Can I use Angular1 plugin in Angular2 application?

Tags: angularjs, angular

I am very new to Angular 2 and would like to know if Angular 1 plugins can be used in Angular 2. I have used [ng-knob](https://radmie.github.io/ng-knob/) in ionic 1 app. Some suggested to use jQuery knob instead but I really want to use ng-knob as it has many more options.

Is it possible to use ng-knob in angular 2? Even if there is a harder way I would not hesitate to try it but I really wan't to use ng-knob.

Any help with sample code is greatly appreciated.

Comment: No. Angular 1 and Angular 2 are different frameworks, and there is no interoperability.

Comment: That's disappointing! Where do I find good plugins for angular 2?

Comment: Angular 2 went final only a few weeks ago. You can't expect the ecosystem to be as rich as the one for Angular 1, which is several years old. But google is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

As **`Angular2`** framework is different from **`Angular1`** framework, I'm afraid to say that you can't use **`Angular1`** plugin(s) for **`Angular2`**.

**`Angular2`** is a *new framework* and recently became ***stable***. So, if you are looking for **`Angular2`** plugin(s), its very hard to find them(as of now) as community is still developing **`Angular2`** plugin(s).

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Upgrading with The Upgrade Adapter section in angular.io - point 2 and other sections till 8.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html

Use angular.umd.js file instead of angular.dev.js or angular.js for 2.x. It supports both angular1 application and angular2 application to run side by side. This way you can use 1.x plugin with angular 1.x application and still run angular 2.x application side by side. You can use Zone.js to merge two way binding between angular 1.x application and 2.x application.

But this can be complex and if you are not comfortable with advanced hacks, you should take the answer of using 1.x plugins in 2.x versions. Unless you are ready to port your 1.x plugin to 2.x plugin yourself.

Zone.js intro - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V9Bbp6Hh2YE Good resource from Misko.